# Display Hidden Textbox/Listbox by selecting the items from another list box

Tags: listbox, hidden

I am new at C#/.net programming and am creating a example website.I need the code for displaying a hidden textbox/listbox by selecting the item from another listbox.I've tried the code which is not correct,

```
        protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Sales");
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Inventory");
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Employee");
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Cash Drop");
        TextBox1.Visible = false;
        if (ListBox1.SelectedItem.value == "Sales" )
        {
            TextBox1.Visible = true;  
        }    

     }
```

can anybody help me please!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBox1.Visible = false;
            ListBox1.Items.Clear();
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Sales");
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Inventory");
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Employee");
            ListBox1.Items.Add("Cash Drop");
        }
    }
    protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ListBox1.SelectedItem.Text == "Sales")
        {
            TextBox1.Visible = true; 
        }    
    }
```

And dont forget to turn `AutoPostBack="true"` in your Listbox :

```
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:ListBox>
```